# non-expensive way to check if object belongs_to scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**client.rb**:

`scope :no_gender, -> { where(gender: "undisclosed") }
  scope :debtors, -> { where("balance < ?", 0) }`

**clients/index.html.haml** expected behaviour:

```
  - @clients.each do |client|
    = client.name
    = client.debtors? #gives true/false
    = client.no_gender? #gives true/false
```

Is there a non-expensive way to check the query for each object in the list and display the result? Or should there be an alternative approach?

Comment: `      - @clients.each do |client|
        = Client.debtors.where(id: client.id).present?`
Such a query works, but takes a lot of memory...

Comment: `client.debtors?` and `client.no_gender?` are scopes? Should it be a error of undefined method here?

Comment: your question doesn't really make sense, i don't see belongs_to relation, `debtors?` and `no_gender?` return boolean based on client attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the 2 instance methods in the `Client` model called `debtors?` and `no_gender?`

```
def no_gender?
  self.gender == "undisclosed"
end

def debtors?
  self.balance < 0
end
```

What you have shown are scopes. They are not to call with `Client` instances like `client` you have in your haml teamplate. Scopes have their own usecases, but not for this specific case you presented.

Comment: thanks for explaining the scopes part. will go with this solution